# Ruby scopes: Diference between MyClass.new and ::MyClass.new

Tags: ruby, scope

I know that the double colon (::) is basically a namespace resolution operator. But in this particular case, I'm not sure in which scope I'm working. Does it mean that I want MyClass class from the ruby core? Sort of like ~ means home directory in bash..

Comment: Correct! Sorry for the duplication, but thank you for the link :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine the following code:

```
class A
  def a
    puts 'TOPMOST'
  end
end

module B
  class A
    def a
      puts 'NESTED'
    end
  end
  def self.topmost
    ::A.new.a
  end
  def self.nested
    A.new.a
  end
end
```

`B.topmost` will print `"TOPMOST"`, and `B.nested` will print `"NESTED"`.

So, `::A` means not “from ruby core”, but rather “from no module.”

Comment: Thank you for your answer, really helped :)!